# Material UI Flexbox issue

Tags: reactjs, sass, material-ui, jss

I have an issue where for some reason the max-width on a grid element is being set to 16% but I'm not sure why. This is in a react app using sass, jss, and material UI. It also works perfectly fine locally, but the problem gets shown when I build the app and put it into production (which has made it really "fun" to debug. I'm not quite sure what's causing this.

```
import React from "react";

// @material-ui/core components
import withStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";

const style = {
  grid: {
    margin: "0 -15px",
    width: "calc(100% + 30px)"
    // '&:before,&:after':{
    //   display: 'table',
    //   content: '" "',
    // },
    // '&:after':{
    //   clear: 'both',
    // }
  }
};

function GridContainer({ ...props }) {
  console.log('GridContainer', props)
  const { classes, children, className, ...rest } = props;

  let formattedClassName = className ? className : ''

  return (
    <Grid container {...rest} className={classes.grid + " " + formattedClassName + " " + 'classes-grid'}>
      {children}
    </Grid>
  );
}

export default withStyles(style)(GridContainer);
```

[image: css in production app]

I don't have a min-width: 600 anywhere in the app so I'm not sure where this is coming from.

Anyone have any idea of the issue or even a good way to go about debugging this? (I've been at this for hours)

adding index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
      homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/apple-icon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.css">
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.js"></script>
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>Manager</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `media (min-width: 600px)` is coming from material-ui css

Answer (score 0):

I ran a similar problem when tried to make a production build of my app, that uses material-ui. I manage to solve by adding a [JSS Provider](https://cssinjs.org/) like this, see if it works:

```
import JssProvider from "react-jss/lib/JssProvider";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    <JssProvider>
      *the rest of your material-ui components*
    </JssProvider>
  }
}
```

Comment: definitely a good suggestion, but unfortunately, that didn't work for me. Any other ideas?

Comment: I once had a problem regarding the index.html, I generated my project with `react-create-app` and for some reason, there where some configuration that limited the screen size, consequentially my component sizes and margins, you could look there

Comment: I added my index.html stuff. I tried removing the viewport stuff but that didn't work either. anything standing out to you?

Comment: Huuum, didn't notice anything, maybe try using `<body style="width: 100%;">`

Comment: What I don't understand is why are you having problems with `Flexbox` but using `Grid`. I'm using `Flexbox` like this in my app: `<Box display="flex" flexWrap="wrap" justifyContent="center" alignItems="center" minHeight='calc( 100vh - 12rem )'>`. You could add width configuration or other there